# Difficulty fixing an infinite loop

Tags: loops, forever

I have to write a program that people can choose geometrical figures and calculate their volume or area whatever.

When the user selects an incorrect input, it'll give them an error message (pls choose number again). However, when user select any letter, this input will cause the program to loop forever. I suspect that the `goto` statement is part of the problem and I'm not sure how to write this program without it. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
int a,i;
float r,h,s,ya,kk,uk;
float pi=22/7.0;
g:printf("number pls\n");
printf("cylinder:1\sphere:2\ncube:3\nrectangle:4\npyramid:5\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
switch(a)
{
case 1: i=1;
        e:printf("%d.h pls ",i);
        scanf("%f",&h);
        printf("%d.r pls ",i);
        scanf("%f",&r);
        ya=pi*r*r;
        s=ya*h;
        printf("%d.: %.2f'\n\n\n",i,s);
        i=i+1;
goto e;
break;
case 2: i=1;
        d:printf("%d.r\n",i);
        scanf("%f",&r);
        s=(4/3.0)*pi*r*r*r;
        printf("%d.: %.2f \n\n",i,s);
        i=i+1;
goto d;
break; 
case 3: i=1;
        c:printf("%d.kk pls\n",i);
        scanf("%f",&kk);
        s=kk*kk*kk;
        printf("%d.: %.2f dir\n\n\n",i,s);
        i=i+1;
goto c;
break;
case 4: i=1;
        b:printf("%d.kk pls ",i);
        scanf("%f",&kk);
        printf("%d.uk pls ",i);
        scanf("%f",&uk);
        printf("%d.h pls ",i);
        scanf("%f",&h);
        s=kk*uk*h;
        printf("%d. %.2f \n\n",i,s);
        i=i+1;
goto b;

break;
case 5:
a:      printf("%d.kk pls",i);
        scanf("%f",&kk);
        printf("%d.uk pls",i);
        scanf("%f",&uk);
        printf("%d.h pls",i);
        scanf("%f",&h);
        ya=kk*uk;
        s=(1/3.0)*ya*h;
        printf("%d.%.2f \n\n\n",i,s);
goto a;


break;
default: printf("ERROR pls choose number again.\n");
goto g;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, all of your switch-cases contain infinite loops because of the `goto`. As a tip for pretty much always: just don't use `goto`. You can make everything work without `goto`. In this case however, I don't even know what is supposed to happen with the `goto`s. You need a condition that stops the loop otherwise your `goto`s just act like a `while(true)`

Comment: yes, my all switch-cases contain infinite loops but i wanted theem. i thought that user can want to calculate result more than one. if you have a free time, pls write that code and first f.e enter 2 or 3, later a or any letter. you will see my problem. both are different. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

1. Just include an option for exit in your menu
2. Remove goto statements
3. Enclose your switch within a do-while loop that will run unless you enter the choice for exit

Like This:

```
printf("cylinder:1\sphere:2\ncube:3\nrectangle:4\npyramid:5\nexit:6\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
do{
switch(a)
{
case 1: //code goes here
       break;
case 2: //code goes here
       break;
.
.
.
.
case 6: break;
}

}while(a!=6);
```

Hope it Helps!!